# How to create a logout button in Node.js/Socket.io app

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have been working on an online game in node and Socket.io (with basically all of the game's state being in Socket.io), but one thing has been bugging me. Right now, a user has to close the page to disconnect from the server. Obviously this needs to be much more elegant, and I need a proper "Logout" button.

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to make one. I searched on Google for an answer, and I have combed through SO. I went digging through the Socket object in Socket.io, and I have tried these 3 related-sounding methods of flipping something on the Socket object to disconnect that user:

```
socket.disconnected = true;
      //and
socket.manager.connected[socket.id] = false;
      //and
socket.manager.open[socket.id] = false;
```

But none of these change the fact that the user is still connected. How is this done?

Comment: try socket.disconnect();

Answer (score 0):

On client side you might subscribe to event of disconnection:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('disconnected');
});
```

Same on server side in order to make sure your logic is aware of such behaviour.
Then in order to allow user manually disconnect you can actually close connection directly:

```
socket.disconnect();
```

Or if some extra interaction with server needed you can emit message to server 'disconnect me', then server will perform own stuff, optionally can emit response to client and call `socket.disconnect()`;